# separar caráteres especiais

Tags: python, unicode

Tenho um ficheiro de texto deste gênero:

```
Olá podes dizer-me quando o 1 passa aqui? ele passa, quando passar o Carlos Alberto.
```

Preciso de em `python` retirar caráteres especiais,como pontuação, números, letras maiúsculas, tornar os caráteres com acento em caracteres normais e separar cada carater individualmente. Algo como isto:

```
o, l, a, p, o, d, e, s, d, i, z, e, r, m, e, q, u, a, n, d, o, o, p, a, s, s, a a, q, u, i, e, l, e, p, a, s, s, a, q, u, a, n, d, o, p, a, s, s, a, r, o, a, a, r, l, o, s, a, l, b, e, r, t, o
```

Há algum `split` ou com o uso do `import re` que faça tudo isto?

Tenho isso:

```
#letra minuscula
data = ''.join(data).lower()
#tirar os nuneros
data = re.sub('#\d{3}\/\d{3}', '', data)

nfkd = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', data)
dataNova = u"".join([c for c in nfkd if not unicodedata.combining(c)])
dataNovaNova = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 \\\]', '', dataNova)

lista= []
lista = list(dataNovaNova)
```

Onde data é uma string

Answer (score 2):

Sim, mas não está relacionado com "split". 
É possível converter a string toda pra minúsculas, e usar a função normalize  do módulo `unicodedata`,  como você usou,  para separar os acentos e as letras em caracteres distintos.

Issso feito, basta usar um filtro normal, com uma list comprehension, para incluir apenas os caracteres que estejam na categoria de "caracteres minúsculos" do Unicode - isso é, aqueles para os quais a função `unicodedata.category` retorna `'Ll'`.

```
import unicodedata

def normalize_chars(text):
    text = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", a.lower())  
    return [char for char in text if unicodedata.category(char) == 'Ll']
```

A saída dessa função para a frase que você passou como exemplo é:

```
['o', 'l', 'a', 'p', 'o', 'd', 'e', 's', 'd', 'i', 'z', 'e', 'r', 'm', 'e', 'q', 'u', 'a', 'n', 'd', 'o', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'a', 'a', 'q', 'u', 'i', 'e', 'l', 'e', 'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'a', 'q', 'u', 'a', 'n', 'd', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'a', 'r', 'o', 'c', 'a', 'r', 'l', 'o', 's', 'a', 'l', 'b', 'e', 'r', 't', 'o']
```

**ps**: Não sei qual uso você vai ter pra isso - mas o pacote `extradict` no pypi Python tem um tipo dicionário que trabalha automaticamente com chaves normalizadas - pode ser que sirva para o uso que você tem em mente. Exemplo de uso:

```
In [3]: import extradict                                                                                 

In [4]: dct = extradict.NormalizedDict()                                                                 

In [5]: dct["maca"] = "Vermelha"                                                                         

In [6]: dct["Maçã"]                                                                                      
Out[6]: 'Vermelha'
```

O pacote "extradict" pode ser instalado com `pip install extradict`. (disclaimer: eu sou o autor).